# Could not invoke constructor for CreatePrograms[0] (FitNesse SLiM)

Tags: java, eclipse, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I have followed the directions from this website (https://schuchert.wikispaces.com/FitNesse.Tutorials.0.Java) to the t, however I cannot get the code on FitNesse to run clean.

I am consistently getting the following exceptions:

|Create Programs Could not invoke constructor for CreatePrograms[0]

|House The instance decisionTable_1.setName. does not exist

Here is my code. I have ensured my classpath is correct. Thank you for your time and consideration - I am very frustrated and confused with this.

```
!contents -R2 -g -p -f -h
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path fitnesse-standalone.jar

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}

!path Users/Julianne/src/fitnesse-tutorials/DVR/bin/
|import|
|com.om.example.dvr.fixtures|


!|Create Programs                                        |
|Name |Channel|DayOfWeek|TimeOfDay|DurationInMinutes|id? |
|House|4      |Monday   |19:00    |60               |$ID=|
```

Comment: The format of my wiki code above (beginning with !|Create Programs) is correct, it just was skewed when posted.

Comment: Also using Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)

Comment: In addition, I did add the class CreatePrograms.java in Eclipse under the com.om.example.dvr.fixtures package. So, that is not missing.

Answer (score 1):

> Could not invoke constructor for CreatePrograms[0]

This error tells you that the test execution cannot find the fixture code in the classpath (accumulated from `!path` statements) that it launches.

It looks like you are giving a relative path here

```
!path Users/Julianne/src/fitnesse-tutorials/DVR/bin/
```

Given that you are running on Mac OS, if you specify it without the preceding '/', it becomes a relative path from the location that you launch your server.

Another thing to check is that ensure right under `.../bin` you have `com/om/example/dvr/fixtures` and the .class files are there.

---

On a side note: A useful trick to check the resulted classpath for the test execution is to add the following block to somewhere on test page (or included setup page)

```
|script     |java properties|
|show   |property   |java.class.path|
```

Answer (score 0):

try to edit the root page and define classpath and variables there: i.e. http://localhost:8090/root

```
#!***> Classpath

!path ${java.class.path}
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}

#*!
```

Comment: it does not matter where you put the `!path` statement. It will only affect the sequence in the final generated classpath string if the !path is in a subpage (behind) or on a root page (in the front).

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I added the class package name in the content.txt under SetUp folder so somewhat similar structure would be there to setup classpath for the test.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because of missing class file or jar file in the path.

Try using below in the same test page rather than in setup page or root page:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path target/*.jar
!path lib/*.jar
```

where,

`targer/*.jar` = For maven project only after `mvn clean install`.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same error for a few days. I found that I was including too much information in my !path on the fitnesse page. I was including information which was already in my JAVA "package" statement.

If the class is within a package provide the path to the folder where the package starts.

for example, my CreditsForPayment.Class includes "package jukebox.fixtures;".  The complete path to my class is:
C:\Users\Brandon\IdeaProjects\untitled\out\production\untitled\jukebox\fixtures\CreditsForPayment.Class

, but in order for Fitnesse to properly find my class, I must use the path.

C:\Users\Brandon\Ideaprojects\untitled\out\production\untitled

with

|import|

|jukebox.fixtures| in my Fitnesse page.

Then you can go ahead with calling the class.

!|CreditsForPayment|

|payment|credits?|

|1|4|

From the https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-fitnesse example.